# array out of index error

Tags: java

I get the error on the line " temp.set_account_id(Integer.parseInt(st[1].trim()));". here is the code, i don't know why it is giving me an exception. help will be appreciated.

```
 public static int readFile(String filename, Customer[] review)throws IOException{

          int count=0;
          Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File (filename));

          /*Reading the first record separatly*/
                      Customer first = new Customer();

                      String[] a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_account_id(Integer.parseInt(a[1].trim()));

                      a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_name(a[1].toUpperCase().trim());

                      a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_address(a[1].trim());

                      a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_phone_number(a[1].trim());

                      a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_date_of_birth(a[1].trim());

                      a = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      first.set_balance(Double.parseDouble(a[1].trim()));

                      review[0]= first;
                      count = count+1;

                 while (scan.hasNext()&& count>0){
                       Customer temp = new Customer();
                       String[] st = scan.nextLine().split("=");

                       for(int i=1;i<count;i++){
                             if(Integer.parseInt(st[1].trim())== review[i].get_accountid()){ // checking for duplicate records
                                  System.out.println("This account id is already in use so the record won't be read");
                                  for (int k=0; k<6; k++)
                                       scan.nextLine();
                          }
                             else
                                break;
                     }


                      temp.set_account_id(Integer.parseInt(st[1].trim()));

                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      temp.set_name(st[1].toUpperCase().trim());

                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      temp.set_address(st[1].trim());

                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      temp.set_phone_number(st[1].trim());

                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      temp.set_date_of_birth(st[1].trim());

                      st = scan.nextLine().split("=");
                      temp.set_balance(Double.parseDouble(st[1].trim()));

                      if (scan.hasNextLine()){
                          scan.nextLine();
              }

                          int j;
                          for(j=0;j<count;j++){

                            if (temp.get_name().compareTo(review[j].get_name())<0){ // Putting records in ascending order
                                break;
                            }
                         }

                      count=count+1;
                      for (int k=count;k>j;k--){
                          review[k]=review[k-1];
                      }

                      review[j]= temp;

                         if (count>=30){
                         System.out.println("The number of records read has exceeded the limit and it will stop reading now");
                         break;
              }

        }

        System.out.println("The number of records read= " + count);
        //System.out.println(count);
        return count;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try watching the variable st by having a break point at line. set_account_id(Integer.parseInt(st[1].trim()))

It would be an empty string

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the scanned line in `String[] a = scan.nextLine().split("=");` does not contain a '=' character. Take a debugger and check the value returned by `scan.nextLine()` and `a`.

Answer (score 0):

If `scan.nextLine()` would return a string with no `=` you'd get an array of length 1. You access the second element `[1]` and if there is none, you get that exception.

Answer (score 0):

aah i forgot to move forward after reading in the first record. i just did a couple of nextline() so that the input string won't be empty.